# Routes in laravel 5.2 are not automatically redirecting to login if not authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have done multiple authentication in Laravel 5.2, everything is working fine . I am able to authenticate admin,redirect to dashboard and logout successfully. But the problem is that when user is not authenticated and I put route of dashboard in url then it opens dashboard even if admin is not authenticated.

My Admin Model

```
<?php

 namespace App\Models;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class System_admin extends Authenticatable
{
protected $guard="admins";
protected $table="system_admin";
protected $primaryKey="admin_id"; 
protected $fillable = [
    'admin_name', 'admin_email', 'admin_password','city_id','admin_address','admin_mobile','admin_status'
];

public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->admin_password;
}
}
```

My config/auth.php

```
      <?php

 return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    //for admin
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    //for admin
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\System_admin::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
| that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
| table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],

],

];
```

My Middleware AdminAuth.php

```
      <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class AdminAuth
 {
 /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admins')
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/admin');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

app/kernel.php

```
      <?php

 namespace App\Http;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

 class Kernel extends HttpKernel
 {
 /**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,



];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],



];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admins' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuth::class,
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
}
```

LoginController.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use \Auth;
use Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
public function viewlogin()
{
    return view('admin.login');
}

public function checklogin(Request $request)
{
     $credentials=array('admin_email' => $request->input('email'),'password' => $request->input('password'));

     if(Auth::guard('admins')->attempt($credentials)) 
         return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
     else
        return redirect('/admin')->with('error','Invalid Username or Password');
}

public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard('admins')->logout();
    return redirect()->intended('/admin');
}
}
```

Routes

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['admins']], function () 
 {

Route::get('/admin','Admin\LoginController@viewlogin');
Route::post('/admin/login','Admin\LoginController@checklogin');


Route::get('/admin/dashboard','Admin\AdminController@dashboard');
Route::get('/admin/logout','Admin\LoginController@logout');
Route::resource('/admin/movies','Admin\MovieController');
Route::resource('/admin/states','Admin\StateController');
Route::resource('/admin/cities','Admin\CityController');
Route::resource('/admin/tax','Admin\TaxController');
Route::resource('/admin/smsgateway','Admin\SmsgatewayController');
Route::resource('/admin/smtpgateway','Admin\SmtpgatewayController');
Route::resource('/admin/paymentgateway','Admin\PaymentgatewayController');

 });



Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {


 });
```

When I am logged in and I open Dashboard then I can see the credentials of logged admin.

[image]

But when I log out, and again visit dashboard it should redirect to login but it's not redirecting to login page.

[image]

Kindly help me as none of questions on stackoverflow has got the answer which I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the auth middleware etc

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['admins', 'auth']], function (){..}
```

As this will do the checking for users etc, also within 5.2 you no longer need the middleware `web`as well, as this is baked into the system automatically.

Comment: If I add this code Route::group(['middleware' => ['admins', 'auth']], function (){..}   then it is using  going to middleware/Authenticate.php  and is redirecting to the something else which I don't want.

Comment: so your created your own authentication and middleware to accomodate your requirements, as the built in ones are customisable and editable?

Comment: Yes simon, as I have to authenticate 4 types of users i.e Wallet User, Admin, Staff and Service users, I thought it would be better to create own authentication and middleware .. But I am stucked here

Comment: could you not utilise larvels ACLGuards  methods, for this so using permissions etc, thus you can keep the standard auth middleware?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of changes in this code , finally I found that where I was going wrong.
The problem was with middleware isn't calling ,so I thought may be it is not registered properly in kernel so I edited kernel file like

I removed admins from middleware group and copied all middlewares to global middleware like this

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http;

 use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

 class Kernel extends HttpKernel
 {
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,



];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],



];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admins' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuth::class,
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
}
```

After doing these changes now my problem of redirection is solved and it's working fine without any problem.